# Mysql gerando erro ao criar foreign key: Error Code: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql

O mysql está retornando esse erro pra mim sempre que tento adicionar foreign key nessas tabelas, porém já conferi os tipos de ambos os campos e está tudo igual.

A tabela onde tenho a chave primária que estou tentando referenciar na outra tabela.

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `internal_client_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `codigo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `razao_social` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cnpj` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `clients_codigo_unique` (`codigo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `clients_razao_social_unique` (`razao_social`),
  UNIQUE KEY `clients_cnpj_unique` (`cnpj`),
  KEY `clients_internal_client_id_foreign` (`internal_client_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

A tabela que contém a foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE payrolls ( 
  importing_user_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  file_name VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
  file_id VARCHAR(35) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
  event_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  VALUE DECIMAL(12,2) DEFAULT NULL, 
  YEAR VARCHAR(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
  MONTH VARCHAR(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
  user_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  client_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Já tentei destas formas:

```
ALTER TABLE payrolls ADD 
FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES clients(id);
ALTER TABLE `payrolls` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_clients` FOREIGN KEY ( `client_id` ) REFERENCES `clients` ( `id` ) ;
```

Comment: Veja no manual a sintaxe correta para declarar uma foreign key.

Comment: @anonimo já vi meu rei.

Comment: Verifique se as engines são iguais -> show create table nomeDAtabela

Comment: A entidade `payrolls` possui algum registro? Caso possua, verifique se existe alguma referência em `client_id` a algum registro que não esteja presente na entidade `clients`.

Comment: Você está usando a engine [MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) que não suporta chaves estrangeiras.

Comment: @MarcosXavier ,  era iso mesmo! Engine errada!

Comment: @AugustoVasques era isso mesmo, obrigado!